# Keep beginning of current fold on top of the screen

Tags: indentation, folding, statusline

I've googled around but can't find anything about this.

There is a case: when I navigate deep down through large blocks of code in (for example) python, it would be useful to see which method, function, or loop I am currently in, when the start is not on screen (because it runs off the top of the screen).

So, consider such block of code:

```
def large_ugly_function():
    ... many lines of code ...
    for i in list_of_items:
        one_action(i)
        i.method()
        event_trigger()
        ... bla-bla-bla around 20-30 lines of code
        ... another for loop or function
        ... <current line>: screen goes down and I can't see the current line part of what loop
```

So I need to see something like header of current fold in "sticky" way: while I navigate through code deep down. It can be written in status line or somewhere else.
For this example for  in status-line it would be something like:

```
large_ugly_function->[for i in list_of_items:]->[another for loop or function]
```

Does anybody know how it can be achieved? Maybe some extensions? How it can be googled?

**UPDATE**
Just wrote this question and found close to what I need but not fully:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634826/vim-show-function-name-in-status-line

I want something closer to folding: so function or loop or other logical block of code

**UPDATE 2**
Also close to this thing can be achieved with TagBar status line integration.

Comment: This is not what you *want* but `?for<Esc>` is a very quick and very cheap way to know where you are.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Well, it's quite interesting - try to use it. But really I want to find out this feature already implemented in status-line or something like it. I can't believe that there is no plugin which already do this.

Comment: tagbar with airline does provide this.

Comment: Could you please provide a config for this? Because the only way I see how TagBar can provide this is `tagbar#currenttag` function. And this is not what I need (but close as I wrote): it shows only the current function, and I'm talking about something like last fold level.

Comment: @pryg_skok I know this is not what you want but maybe you could imagine a totally different way to do what you want: you could use 2 different splits `:e foo.py`, go to the line you want to keep, `:sp` to split your screen with the buffer at the same position in each split and then move only one split (make sure that `scrollbind` is off)

Comment: @statox yes, interesting idea - the problem is - there is no update of upper split when I switch to new block of code: loop, function. So if it's possible to add update state to this workaround it would be working.

Comment: @pryg_skok it would require a bit of vimscript but I think that can be done... When I have some free time I'll look into it :-)

Comment: @pryg_skok: [Here is](https://gist.github.com/statox/81cc7cecadca2bcfb038944ee47b20dd) an early test. Add the lines in your vimrc, open a *.py file and split the window (`:sp` and resize the upper split so it is ~10 lines). Now when you move the cursor in the bottom split the beginning of the current indent level is on the middle line of the upper split. Does it look like something you want? Of course it still need improvement but I think that could be a start

Comment: @statox wow! it works! ;) Yes, it's pretty much like what I'm looking for.
I thought about only one line like fold graph as you want: func->loop->another_func->... because I think it shouldn't eat a lot of space on screen and should be easily integrated with top bar (with tabs or buffers) or airline, lightline, etcline...

So, if you evolve the idea I would be very appreciative and also I think it's good plugin in addition to tagbar to code navigation. Also if you will write it not in vimL but in python - I help with development.

Comment: @pryg_skok: See my answer, I reduced the size of the upper split, I think the answer describes pretty precisely the code so you should be able to tweak it as you like. The integration with the tagline/airline/*line plugins is pretty hard IMO. I probably won't spend time on this to translate the code to python but feel free to get the code of my answer and translate it by yourself :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So following the idea I suggested in comments here is what I've come up with:

First let's demonstrate it with a gif (I'm not sure why the cursor leaves this ugly mark):

[image]

The idea is to:

- Set the foldmethod to `indent` because it works well with python. (But I guess using `marker` or `manual` would work too)
- Open a split which will contain the "context information" i.e. the beginning of the fold the cursor is currently on.
- Each time the cursor is moved, the upper split is updated to show the correct context information.

The code is in two parts, first the function:

```
function! PinFold()
    " save current position
    let saveCursor =  getcurpos()

    " Go to upper split, open all folds and go to the same line as bottom split
    wincmd k
    normal! zR
    execute "normal! " . saveCursor[1] . "G"
    " Go to the beginning of the fold and put the line top of the upper split
    normal! [zk
    normal! zt

    " Go back to bottom split and restore position
    wincmd j
    call setpos('.', saveCursor)
endfunction
```

It is pretty self-explained:

- Save the position of the cursor
- Go on the upper split, at the same line as the bottom split
- Go to the beginning of the fold and put the line in the top of the split
- Go back to bottom split

And to make it work automatically, an augroup:

```
augroup pythonFold
    autocmd BufReadPre *.py setlocal foldmethod=indent
    autocmd BufReadPost *.py wincmd k | resize 3 | wincmd j
    autocmd CursorMovedI *.py call PinFold()
    autocmd CursorMoved *.py call PinFold()
augroup END
```

It will set the correct foldmethod and open the upper split when opening a new python buffer. And then each time the cursor is moved in normal or in insert mode, the previous function is called.

**Note** The while process can probably be improved (better handling of already open buffer, multiple splits in a tab, etc) but this is left as an exercise to the reader ;-)

---

Related help topics:

- [`:h :augroup`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#%3Aaugroup)
- [`:h :autocmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#%3Aautocmd)
- [`:h autocmd-events`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd%2Devents)
- [`:h getcurpos()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getcurpos%28%29)
- [`:h :wincmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Awincmd)
- [`:h folding`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/fold.txt.html#folding)
- [`:h [z`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/fold.txt.html#%5Bz)
- [`:h z.`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/scroll.txt.html#z.)

Comment: Just small edit: to resize upper split you need to fix your command:
`autocmd BufReadPost *.py wincmd s | wincmd k | resize 3 | wincmd j`

Comment: Right, it's done.

Comment: I've made small modifications on top of your idea to implement "intergration" :) with lightline [here](https://gist.github.com/pryg-skok/7e27d897fc3a19ebc89d33b062eac536)
I've removed split and notice `normal! [zkk`  -- it's still not perfect finding the beginning of fold and sometimes wrong detect it.Also double `kk` looks like hack. Do you know how it can be done better?

Comment: @pryg_skok: Nice evolution. First I'd say that you can get rid of lines 13, 14 and 17. Then about `[z`, [`:h fold-commands`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/fold.txt.html#fold%2Dcommands) seems to indicate that it is the way to go (`kk` should not be necessary) so if it doesn't work well maybe you can do something with a loop which will search the correct line based on the return of `foldlevel()` (See [`:h foldlevel()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#foldlevel%28%29))